# Force ffmpeg to ignore error when connecting failed

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp, live-streaming

I'm trying to deploy a live stream delivery system with nginx and nginx-rtmp-module.

For every node in my system, I wish it could 'forward' the live stream received to downstream node. I try to implement it by following config in my nginx.conf:

`exec_push ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/src/test -vcodec copy -strict -2 -ar 44100 -ac 1 -f flv rtmp://<downstreaming A>/src/test -f flv rtmp://<downstreaming B>/src/test`

it works when everything runs well, but if the downstream node is down, this command will exit and none of the downstream nodes could receive the live stream.

How could I force ffmpeg to ignore the `connetion refused`, or is there any better alternative to my implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot ignore `connection refused` since RTMP uses TCP which needs a connection.

If I understood correctly you're trying to transcode a RTMP source and send it to a number of servers.

1. You could duplicate your command to send to each downstream node
   individually but you'll be doing the transcoding twice.
2. An alternative is to transcode and publish the transcoded stream using
   `ffserver` on the same machine and then push to / pull on each downstream server

Comment: That is just what I want to do.

Comment: The possible problem of solution 1 is that the CPU may be overloaded when there are too many downstream node, I feared. While the problem of the solution 2 is that only upstream node know the begin of a live stream and the downstream nodes need an extra notification.

Comment: Then transcode once and push to `ffserver` then `exec_push` using multiple commands.